# Rotate/Lerp Gameobject 90 degrees (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

Alright, I'm new to this stuff and the internet is confusing me pretty hard.
You have Euler Angles, Quaternions; one uses degrees, the other radians, you should use lerp, slerp, lookat, you can't set pivots manually without parent objects... etc.

What I want to do is *gradually* rotate a gameobject around its pivot point 90 degrees clockwise in Z whenever I press a key. It's like a Tetris block.

I'm really looking for a short, simple explanation so I understand what I'm doing and to avoid further confusion. Help would really be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: use the linear interpolate functions in combination with a coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set transform.rotation with Quaternion.

Simply you can do this

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z+90));
```

Quaternion.Euler uses degrees, if you want to use it with radian, you should use Quaternion.EulerAngles.

Answer (score 0):

I think

````
``` lang-C#
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
    }
```
````

would do that. Just replace the key A with the key you want.